# Letter "p" ruining vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, diagrams

I have a simple diagram I have created.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{10pt}
    \begin{picture}(24,4)
      \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
      \put(0,2){$\underbrace{\strut \fcolorbox{black}{teal0}{\framebox(6,2){Preamble}}\fcolorbox{black}{purp0}{\framebox(7,2){Start code}}}_\textrm{Stage 1: estimate M}$}
      \put(13,2){$\underbrace{\strut \fcolorbox{black}{lime0}{\framebox(5,2){Data}}\fcolorbox{black}{orange0}{\framebox(6,2){Stop code}}}_\textrm{Stage 2: sample and decode}$}
    \end{picture}
    \caption{Packet format.}
    \label{fig:packet}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

and it creates the following: 
[image]

However, if you look closely you will notice the text in the last box is out of alignment with the text in the other boxes because of the "p". I would like to put it in alignment. Solution should be as close to the original image as possible, and not require additional packages like TikZ.

Comment: using the `amsmath` package, one can simply "smash" the bottom of a word with descenders: `\smash[b]{Stop} code`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please always post complete documents showing all packages (and colours) used. I made up some different colours.

As you are in picture mode anyway it is easier to directly control the position of the braces using `\put` coordinates, and you can hide the depth of the text using `\raisebox.`
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{10pt}
    \begin{picture}(24,4)
      \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
      \put(0,2){\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\framebox(6,2){Preamble}}%
                \fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\framebox(7,2){Start code}}%
                \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\framebox(5,2){Data}}%
                \fcolorbox{black}{green}{\framebox(6,2){\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{Stop code}}}}

      \put(0,0){\makebox(13.2,2){\upbracefill}\makebox(11.2,2){\upbracefill}}

      \put(0,-1){\makebox(13.2,2){Stage 1: estimate M}%
                \makebox(11.2,2){Stage 2: sample and decode}}



    \end{picture}
    \caption{Packet format.}
    \label{fig:packet}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Concise answer, clean code, and you improved the braces for bonus points. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't notice it before, but this answer does not include the text under the braces as in the original.

Comment: @trav1s well I spotted that after I'd posted but since it's easy to put them back I didn't think it worth re-creating the image:-)

Comment: @trav1s I added the label back to the code:-)

Answer (score 10):

It's all about the placement of the `\strut`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{10pt}
  \begin{picture}(24,4)
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \put(0,2){$\underbrace{\strut \fcolorbox{black}{red}{\framebox(6,2){Preamble}}\fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\framebox(7,2){Start code}}}_\textrm{Stage 1: estimate M}$}%
    \put(13,2){$\underbrace{\strut \fcolorbox{black}{green}{\framebox(5,2){Data}}\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\framebox(6,2){Stop code}}}_\textrm{Stage 2: sample and decode}$}
  \end{picture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{10pt}
  \begin{picture}(24,4)
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \put(0,2){$\underbrace{\fcolorbox{black}{red}{\framebox(6,2){\strut Preamble}}\fcolorbox{black}{blue}{\framebox(7,2){\strut Start code}}}_\textrm{Stage 1: estimate M}$}%
    \put(13,2){$\underbrace{\fcolorbox{black}{green}{\framebox(5,2){\strut Data}}\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\framebox(6,2){\strut Stop code}}}_\textrm{Stage 2: sample and decode}$}
  \end{picture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The upper image is the original output, while the lower one uses a `\strut` in each box. Since you are using `\fcolorbox`, you can create something like

```
\newcommand{\paddedbox}[4][1ex]{%
  {\setlength{\fboxsep}{#1}\fcolorbox{#2}{#3}{\strut\quad#4\quad}}}%
```

which creates a padded box (through setting `\fboxsep`; default is `1ex`), vertically and horizontally (through additional placements of `\quad`s (`1em` space). The code is a little cleaner

```
\begin{center}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{10pt}
  \begin{picture}(24,4)
    \put(0,2){$\underbrace{\paddedbox{black}{red}{Preamble}\paddedbox{black}{blue}{Start code}}_\textrm{Stage 1: estimate M}$}%
    \put(15,2){$\underbrace{\paddedbox{black}{green}{Data}\paddedbox{black}{yellow}{Stop code}}_\textrm{Stage 2: sample and decode}$}
  \end{picture}
\end{center}
```

and produces

[image]

Comment: I should clarify, the original /struts were used to produce spacing between the boxes and the brackets. Your answer is correct that adding a /strut to each box does put them all in alignment with eachother. But now they are slightly higher than center. What I would like is to move the "Stop code" text in the original text down, instead of moving the others up. Sorry if this is getting a little anal retentive!

Comment: @trav1s: Use `\vphantom{S}\smash{Stop code}` The you get the appropriate height of the letter `S` (a capital letter without a descender) but without setting it, followed by a zero height-depth setting of `Stop code` since it's `\smash`ed.

Comment: @trav1s You could adapt Werner's answer to use your custom struts, e.g. `\newcommand*{\mystrut}{\rule[-0.2\baselineskip]{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}}`, and control the height of your boxes that way. I once wrote [a detailed answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86592/10102) with more details if you're interested.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, the same problem with TikZ could be fixed as shown in [Problem with TikZ and vertical alignment of text inside nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19751/problem-with-tikz-and-vertical-alignment-of-text-inside-nodes).

Combining that hint with [Connecting nodes with brace in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112412/13304), it is possible to build the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pdftexcmds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,shadows}

% list of keys
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  border color/.initial=black,
  border color/.get=\bordercol,
  border color/.store in=\bordercol,
  brace color/.initial=black,
  brace color/.get=\bracecol,
  brace color/.store in=\bracecol,
  brace distance/.initial=5pt,
  brace distance/.get=\bracedistance,
  brace distance/.store in=\bracedistance,
  brace position/.initial=north,
  brace position/.get=\bracepos,
  brace position/.store in=\bracepos,
  items height/.initial=1cm,
  items height/.get=\itemheight,
  items height/.store in=\itemheight,
  items width/.initial=3cm,
  items width/.get=\itemwidth,
  items width/.store in=\itemwidth,
  items distance/.initial=\itemwidth,
  items distance/.get=\itemdistance,
  items distance/.store in=\itemdistance,  
}

% list of styles
\tikzset{module/.style={
    draw=\bordercol,
    minimum height=\itemheight,
    minimum width=\itemwidth,
    text height=1.5ex,
    text depth=.25ex,
  },
  brace/.style={
    decoration={brace,raise=\bracedistance,amplitude=0.75em,#1},
    decorate,
    draw=\bracecol,
    very thick,    
  }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\braceddiagram}[3][]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,transform shape,#1] % here we can pass options:
      % scale=0.9,transform shape are used to avoid overfull and underfull boxes

     % counting all the items to be displayed
     \foreach \items/\colors [count=\xi] in {#2}{\global\let\maxnumitem\xi}

     % foreach item we are going to compute at which distance it should be located
     % and then we put it with the module style and with a name <module><num-module>
     \foreach \items/\colors [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
       \path let 
         \n1={0+\xi*\itemdistance} in
         node[module,fill=\colors] (module\xi) at +(\n1,0) {\items};
     }

     % at the end we draw the brace with the comment
     \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\bracepos}{south}=\z@
       \draw[brace=mirror] (module1.south west)--(module\maxnumitem.south east)
        node[below=3*\bracedistance, midway]{#3};
     \else
       \draw[brace] (module1.north west)--(module\maxnumitem.north east)
        node[above=3*\bracedistance, midway]{#3};
     \fi

  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Generic examples:

\braceddiagram[brace distance=4pt]{Bla/red, Bla/blue, Bla/green}{Some comment}

\vspace{1cm}

\tikzset{my style for the diagram/.style={
    brace distance=6pt,
    brace position=south,
  }
}

\braceddiagram[my style for the diagram]{Bla/red, Bla/blue, Bla/green,Bla/yellow}{Some other comment}

\vspace{1cm}

The real example:

\begin{center}
\braceddiagram[my style for the diagram]{Preamble/red, Start code/blue}{Stage 1: estimate M}
\braceddiagram[my style for the diagram]{Data/green,Stop code/yellow}{Stage 2: sample and decode}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]